# Riemann Zeta Zeros and Andronov-Hopf bifurcation

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems, riemann-zeta, bifurcation

I was watching [3Blue1Brown visualizations](https://youtu.be/sD0NjbwqlYw?t=409) of the converging values of Riemann Zeta function $\zeta(s)$.  From 6:41 forward he shows that each how each series $\sum{\frac{1}{n^{s}}}$ maps into a spiral (vector sum) in the complex plane for $\sigma>1$. The focus is the image $\zeta(s)$. The real part ($Re(s), \sigma)$ determines each vectors length while ($Im(s),t$) determines angles.

After sketching some conditions, I am convinced that the vector sum follow patterns similar to Andronov-Hopf bifurcations after $\sigma$ in a discrete dynamical system.

Negative even values ($\sigma=-2n$) determine a limit cycle related to $exp$ period (rotations over the real line on the Riemann Sphere). Positive real part ($\sigma>1$) determines stable nodes (the spirals from 3B1B video). The higher $\sigma$ is, more convoluted is the spiral, hence $\lim_{\sigma\rightarrow \infty}{\zeta(\sigma+it)=1}$. The critical strip $0 < \sigma < 1$ also contains stable focuses, fractional exponents determine sums with fixed points at the real line.For $\sigma = \frac{1}{2}$, the stable focus is exactly at the real line. One can [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=zeta%280.43%20%2Bit%29%20) [values](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=zeta%280.49%20%2Bit%29%20) of $\zeta$ near $\sigma=\frac{1}{2}$ to check the translation of values in the irregular curve representing $Re(\zeta(s))$.

I came here to ask for directions. Am I just another applied mathematician losing time? Is this a valid line of research?

I did not start a formalization, but I was thinking of the following possibilities: (1) Working with orbits on vector fields and then extending the results to the analytic continuation of $\zeta$; (2) Working directly on the dynamical properties of the analytic continuation (e.g. eigenvalues, flow $\phi$ and Liapounoff stability); (3) Working with differential geometry.

Comment: do you follow my answer

Comment: Yes, @reuns, I think so. Thank you very much. What  does r in |\Im(s)|^r mean? Is it from the form  r*e^ti?

Comment: No, the idea is that for $\Re(s) \in (0,1]$ it is unclear how good/bad is the approximation $\zeta(s) \approx \sum_{n=1}^{N(s)-1} n^{-s} +\frac{N(s)^{1-s}}{s-1}$, with $N(s) = 10^{10}$ constant the approximation will be bad for large $\Im(s)$, with $N(s) = e^{|\Im(s)|}$ the approximation will be very good for all $s$, the Riemann siegel formula says with $N(s)= |\Im(s)|$ the approximation will be good for all $s$, and the Lindelof hypothesis predicts that for any $r> 0$ with $N(s) = |\Im(s)|^r$ the approximation will be not too bad too.

Comment: My answer shows $|\zeta(s) -\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} n^{-s} +\frac{N^{1-s}}{s-1}| \le \frac{|s|}{\Re(s)}N^{-s}$ for all $N$ and $s,\Re(s) > 0$

Comment: @reuns would it be possible to approach the special case $\Re(s)=\frac{1}{2}$ through symmetry groups of zeroes on a geometrical construction using unit vectors? For instance, the group action $\phi$ after said dynamical system rationale. The sum of inverse square roots $\sum_{n=1}^{N} n^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ seems interesting.

Comment: I don't see what you mean.

Comment: Consider the vector sum in $\zeta (s)$ as connected line segments with length $\frac{1}{n^{\Re(s)}}$, orthogonally rotated from the previous endpoint by a fixed angle $(e^{i * \text{ln} \Im(s)})$. \Re(\zeta(s)) is given by the projection of the converging point on the real line ($\mathbb{R}$, coincident to the first line segment). For $\zeta (s)=0$, the negative and positive projections cancel out (equal moduli). Since $\Re(s)$ dictates the size of line segments, I find it curious the relationship between $\sum_{n=1}^{N} n^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ and unit vectors in Euclidian spaces.

Comment: From wiki: If a vector's length is determined by its Euclidean norm, when each component of the vector is divided by that length, the new vector will be a unit vector pointing in the same direction. Then,the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ contains the exact sequence with these normalizing factors for vectors whose length correspond to every natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70460/non-trivial-zeros-of-the-zeta-function

Answer (score 1):

For $\Re(s) > 1$ and by analytic continuation for $\Re(s) > 0$ $$\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} n^{-s} = \zeta(s) -\sum_{n=N}^\infty n^{-s} \\ =\zeta(s) - \int_N^\infty x^{-s}dx-\sum_{n=N}^\infty (n^{-s}-\int_n^{n+1}x^{-s}dx)\\= \zeta(s)- \frac{N^{1-s}}{s-1} -\sum_{n=N}^\infty  \int_n^{n+1} \int_n^x st^{-s-1}dtdx\\= \zeta(s)- \frac{N^{1-s}}{s-1} + O( \sum_{n=N}^\infty\int_n^{n+1} |s x^{-s-1}|dx)\\ = \zeta(s)- \frac{N^{1-s}}{s-1} + O(s \int_N^\infty  x^{-\Re(s)-1}dx)\\ = \zeta(s)- \frac{N^{1-s}}{s-1} + O(\frac{s}{\Re(s)}N^{-s})$$ and if you plot $ \frac{N^{1-s}}{s-1}$ for $\Re(s) >1, s \not \in \Bbb{R}$ you'll get a spiral converging to $0$.

If you substract the main term $\frac{N^{1-s}}{s-1} $ then the asymptotic of the second term isn't more mysterious : it is found following quite the same method, which leads to the [Euler McLaurin summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula). What is mysterious is the value of $\sum_{n =1}^N n^{-s} $ for $N$ of "middle size" $N \approx |\Im(s)|^r$.